# Adding sheathing under a concrete tile roof

Tags: roofing, sheathing

I have a concrete tile roof that has just the skip sheathing.  Its common to get squirrels nesting up there because there is nothing there to prevent them from coming in through the eaves.  Is it possible to add additional sheathing behind the existing skip sheathing to help with squirrels and possibly leaks?

Here is the best image I have of the existing sheathing and back of the concrete tiles.

[image]

Comment: I am told the roofers need to remove the tile. Install plywood sheets, covered with felt (tar Paper) then lay new partial sheathing on top to affix the interlocking tile back on the roof. I am tired just thinking of that plus the $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this roof tile is the Spanish terra cotta style(curved or waved shaped) than  plug up the openings at the eaves. What I have done is: 1) cram rolled-up sections of poultry netting into the cavities and mix a batch of mortar keep it fairly dry and trowel it into openings. or 2) get a length of 2-3 inch galvanized roof flashing and snip the outline of each eave opening. Than push it into the eave opening.